# Add Variance Column in R data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 16 columns and I wish to add a column at the end with the row variance of columns 4-16. This would also be ignoring NA values.

Data looks something like this:

```
Chr  Position  end  IA3023  Nam6  Nam9 ...
18    1        2    0.5     0.5   0.5
18    2        3    0       0.25  0.5
18    3        4    0.5     0.3   0.25
```

Would like it to add a row variance in last column:

```
Chr  Position  end  IA3023  Nam6  Nam9 ...   RowVariance
18    1        2    0.5     0.5   0.5        0
18    2        3    0       NA    0.5        0.125
18    3        4    0.5     0.3   0.25       0.0175
```

Comment: What problem have you encountered?

Comment: Take a look at the `apply` function.

Comment: How do you hope to aggregate the variance of 12 different features into one column?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 I think he meant row variance?

Comment: you should be able to put the pieces together from `cbind`, `apply`, `var`, and the `na.rm=TRUE` argument to `var()` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df is the given data frame

Desired output will come from this line

```
     cbind(df, var = apply(df[,4:16], 1, function(x) var(na.omit(x))))
```

Comment: Error in df[, 4:16] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: This worked fabulously! Thank you! I don't have the rep to upvote though

Answer (score 1):

Well, the question is really vague and did not provide an example.

Assuming you meant row variance:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, rowvars := .(rowSums(DT[, 4:16, with = FALSE], na.rm = TRUE)^2/(13-1))]
```

see if it works

Comment: Receive following error: `Error in `[.data.frame`(DT, , `:=`(rowvars, (rowSums(DT[, 4:16, with = FALSE],  : 
  could not find function ":="`

Comment: Did you load the data.table package, I tested it, and it works fine for me.

Comment: Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , 4:16, with = FALSE) : j out of bounds

Comment: This is a column index error. Are you sure you have 16 columns? you can change the column numbers in the bracket to make it suit your actual column range.

Comment: I was stupidly using the wrong data frame and that was why I was receiving the out of bounds error. This argument does work but does not account for the changing amount of NA' values present in each column